# Querydsl поиск с джоинами

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Есть три таблицы:

```
my_entity: id, ....

comment: id, my_entity_id, description_id, date, active ...

description: id, ...
```

В коде это выглядит так:

```
@Table(name = "my_entity")
public class MyEntity {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = my_entity_id, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<@Valid CommentEntity> comments;
}

@Table(name = "comment")
public class CommentEntity {

   @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH}, optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "my_entity_id", nullable = false)
   protected MyEntity myEntity;


    @Column(name = "description_id")
    @Convert(converter = DescriptionConverter.class)
    private Descriprtion description;
}
```

Как видно `MyEntity` имеет массив комметов.

Я использую `QueryDSL`. Я создал `BooleanBuilder`. И пытаюсь туда накидать условие:

Найти сущности (MyEntity) у которых есть коммент с определенным `Description`. Подразумевается, что у меня уже есть экземплят объекта `Description`. При этом в массиве комментов надо брать только  последний по дате активный коммент.

Если бы в `MyEntity` был бы не `Set`, а сразу переменная класса `Comment`, я бы сделал так:

```
builder.and(myEntity.comment.description.eq(description)).
```

Но в моем случае еще надо отобрать последний активный коммент и проверить у недо наличие указаного `description`. И только с такими комментами возвращать `entity`.

Как мне составить такой запрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
QMyEntity user = QMyEntity.myEntity;
QCommentEntity comment1 = QCommentEntity.commentEntity;
QCommentEntity comment2 = QCommentEntity.commentEntity;

List<MyEntity> myEntities =
        queryFactory
                .select(user)
                .from(user)
                .where(JPAExpressions.selectOne()
                        .from(comment1)
                        .where(comment1.myEntity.eq(user)
                                .and(comment1.description.eq(description))
                                .and(comment1.active.eq(true))
                                .and(comment1.date.eq(JPAExpressions.select(comment2.date.max())
                                        .from(comment2)
                                        .where(comment2.myEntity.eq(comment1.myEntity)))))
                        .exists())
                .fetch();
```